# Animate fragment transition when showing and hiding (not replacing)

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, webview, android-transitions

For a web browser with tabs, I have a changing number of fragments with a webview and other views (like title bar ect) for each one. When I change tab, I just call `FragmentTransaction.show()` or `FragmentTransaction.hide()` since I don't want to lose my loaded webview (so no `replace(),` which will delete my fragment and the webview will have to load stuff again).

My problem is, I know how to animate fragment transitions when I call replace. But can I show transitions for just showing or hiding fragments? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you place some of your code here so we can have a clue on what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as you would animate **replace** transition. The only thing you should keep in mind - animate via method with 4 parameters:

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations(@AnimatorRes @AnimRes int enter, @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int exit, @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int popEnter,         @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int popExit);
```

Comment: Indeed, that was as simple as that! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out);
                if (fragment.isHidden()) {
                    ft.show(fragment);
                } else {
                    ft.hide(fragment);
                }
                ft.commit();
```